# Update datastore in Google App Engine from the iPhone

Tags: java, iphone, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on an app that communicates with Google App Engine to update and retrieve user information, but I can't think of a way to modify elements in the datastore.

For example, every user for my app is represented by a User object in the datastore. If this user inputs things like email, phone number, etc into fields inside the iPhone application, I want to be able to update those objects in the datastore. The datastore can be in Java or Python, I'm just looking for an idea that will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not have the iPhone application communicate this information to app engine by making a simple HTTP request?

Specifically, I would do an HTTP POST to the server and include the relevant fields.  Then your app engine request handler would simply store the information in the datastore.

Comment: Ah, I'll definitely look into that. Sounds promising!